Aprilaire 600 "on" light doesn't come on
I changed the media when the humidistat said to change it.  I turned off the humidistat, removed the old media, put new media in, and turned on the humidistat. I noticed that the "on" light did not light.  Also, no water is coming out of the drain tube. I turned the control to "test/reset" and then back to 7; the "on" light flashed once and went out. I have done this several times with the same result. Still no water from the drain tube. I have a small humidistat setting on the thermostat upstairs and it reads 25%; down from its usual reading of 30-33%. When should the "on" light be lite? Suggestions?
